# Allow OpenVPN clients to manually set their IP addresses in tun interface

Tags: openvpn

I need to frequently change the client's IP address manually so modifying the server's configuration every time just seems troublesome.
Is there anything similar to `AllowedIPs` in WireGuard allowing clients to set their own IP addresses inside specific ranges in OpenVPN?
I've tried to just ignore the pushed IP and manually set another one but failed, for that OpenVPN seems to block the traffic whose source IP doesn't match with the allocated one.
`dev tun` and `topology subnet` are used.

Comment: This sounds like a X-Y-problem. *Why* do you need to change the IP's?

Comment: @vidarlo I'm using source-based routing to switch between multiple networks, and running many dedicated OpenVPN instances doesn't seem to be a good solution. Actually I'm switching from WireGuard to OpenVPN, and WireGuard does work perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have somehow misunderstood the error `MULTI: bad source address from client`.
This doesn't mean that OpenVPN is trying to prevent an IP spoofing, but that it has **no routes** to this IP.
See https://openvpn.net/faq/multi-bad-source-address-from-client-packet-dropped-or-get-inst-by-virt-failed/
Like `AllowedIPs` in WireGuard, `iroute` must be added to CCDs to tell OpenVPN the client to which packets should route.
Manually adding proper kernel routes (done by `route`) and `iroute` solved the problem.